# React devtools while developing a Microsoft add-in

Tags: reactjs, office-js, office-ui-fabric, react-devtools

Is it possible to use React Devtools while building / debugging a Microsoft Add-in?

**What I've tried:**

I tried setting up React devtools as a standalone app.

1. npm i -g react-devtools
2. react-devtools
3. Copy `<script>` tag into my code.

The result is that the standalone react-devtools app is open, but it doesn't connect to React.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Office Add-In is hosted in an iframe as a normal React App. If you used (choosing React as script):

```
yo office
```

It should work as long as you place the debugger script in `<head>` in `src\index.html`:

```
<script src="http://localhost:8097"></script>
```

Just make sure you relaunch your add-in.

**Note:** This was my first time creating the Add-In, I was curious, and make sure you follow the "Update Manifest" section here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/quick-start?tabs=visual-studio-code so it will work. It worked without any issues, within 5 minutes.

[image]

Comment: Mohamed - I get an HTTPS <-> HTTP error since React DevTools is running on HTTP, and my add-in is over HTTPS. 

Did you run your add-in over HTTP?  Or did you get DevTools to work with HTTPS?

Comment: @DonP I first opened Chrome to access my add-in (https://localhost:3000) , I accepted the cert that way. Then I opened react devtools and placed http there, it worked. There is a section regarding installing cert of your add-in in the docs, but I didn't do that, I just forced it manually.